# Migrating Data from one to another sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, migration

I would like to migrate few tables from one database server to other database server (both are SQL server). How can I do this? I have heard about SSIS package but never done this. I would like to understand this process in detail.

Source database is refreshed daily. what can I do to refresh my destination database to reflect the source database all the time.

Please help me, I would like to understand this process from beginning till end because I have never done this before.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here are the high level steps.

Create an SSIS project. Use a data flow task for each table. Depending on your requirements you might be able to just clear the tables and just reload them.

Create a new sql agent job on the server to schedule the job. Make sure you schedule after the source database is completely loaded.